# columnDefs header does not show from time to time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I have a very random problem on UI. It looks like the column definitions do not show from time to time. it works fine 9 out of 10 times.

Two gif animations have been included to show what I actually mean as that will help to understand the issue much faster.

The screen below displays the column definition and everything is visible.

[image: Here is working header and we can see it on the last tab]

However, the second picture shows that the header column definitions are not visible

[image: Here is the header which does not show column definitions]

That problem is a completely random problem and I can't see why something like that is happening.

There is a link on official **github** repository for **ui-grid** issue which describes similar situation I have: [ui-grid similar issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3229)
I tried to apply a few things but it does not work e.g. wrapping html page with

```
 <script type="text/ng-template">
```

tag when I use ng-include but it didn't help

Please advice if you had similar problem or you know how to fix it.

**Code snippets:**

```html
<div class="modal-body" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" ng-modal-drag>
  <div class="checkbox pull-right" style="margin-bottom: -40px; position: relative">
    <label class="text-primary">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.updateHighlight()" ng-model="vm.companyMatch.isHighlighted" style="margin-top: 2px; outline: none;">Reviewed
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs" active="tab.active" heading="{{tab.heading}}" select="tab.select()" ng-if="tab.heading != 'Map' || vm.companyCandidates.length > 0">
      <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

The interesting part is that 
    
loads html content and on the first tab the **ui-grid** always works and the problem exists only on the third tab when there is another **ui-grid** element

The related javascript code looks like below:

```js
vm.gridOptions = {
  paginationPageSizes: [5, 10, 25],
  paginationPageSize: 5,
  enableColumnResizing: true,
  enableRowSelection: true,
  enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
  multiSelect: false,

  columnDefs: [{
    field: 'businessName',
    displayName: 'Business name'
  }, {
    field: 'fullAddress',
    displayName: 'Address'
  }, ...],

  onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
    vm.gridApi = gridApi;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending a reasonable amount of time on that issue I finally found the solution to that problem.

[Here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/110_grid_in_modal) is the documentation for **ui-grid** when they encourage to use special javascript function to render grid properly after opening it in modal window.

I have added code snippet below:

```js
$interval( function() {
    $scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();
}, 500, 10);
```

and that thing works for me!